# How does Android know the router administrator interface's local IP?

Tags: wi-fi

I saw:

[image]

This links to the local IP of the router's admin interface.

How does Android know the router administrator interface's local IP?

Comment: Additional info: while the naming of "Manage Router" seems to be only on Samsung, looks like [it's possible for Android in general to get the *gateway*](https://tunecomp.net/find-router-ip-address-on-android/).

Comment: A simple way would be to take the gateway IP of the active network configuration (in your case most likely 192.168.8.1). The advanced way uses [Universal Plug and Play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play) which uses UDP broadcasts to find devices and then query their type/interfaces.

Comment: 1. [Router / gateway address](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2132.html#section-3.5), 2. [DHCP server address](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2132.html#section-9.7), and 3. [DNS server address](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2132.html#section-3.8) are part of the DHCPOFFER message that a DHCP client (Android device in our case) receives as a part of the initial DHCP handshake before IP assignment. So the both parties know whom they are talking to. In simple setups all three addresses mentioned above belong to the same network host i.e. router.

Comment: Thanks both, you're welcome to convert your comments into answers.